# Applescript - Open password protected excel file

Tags: applescript, ms-office, password

Is there a way for Applescript to open an Excel workbook (.xls) that is password protected?

I see that in the library there are functions to check if a workbook has password, but I do not know the proper syntax for opening a wb with password protection.

```
Tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  -- set theWb to path of .... etc.
  open theWb with password "abc" ? <--- what should go here?
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to open a Excel workbook (xlsx, in my example) which is protected either the workbook and/or the sheet. You can use the following script:

```
set passwd to "1234" -- whatever you want
set theWbpath to "/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/number1.xlsx" -- example path
set theWb to "number1.xlsx" -- example file
set theSheet to "sheet1" -- example name of sheet
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open theWbpath                
    unprotect workbook theWb ¬ --> 
        password passwd        --> workbook part, can be left out
    unprotect sheet theSheet ¬ --> 
        password passwd        --> sheet part, can be left out
end tell
```

Comment: I don't know what the sign ¬  means in the AppleScript context so you may have to revise the formatting

Comment: @klanomath, `¬` is: [The Continuation Character](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_lexical_conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH214-SW9)

Comment: tell application "Microsoft Excel"
 open "Macintosh HD:Users:user:Desktop:fileName.xls"
    

it stops at this point, and doesn't continue to do the next line of code which is unprotect workbook theWb

Comment: does it only work for xlsx files?

Comment: It could be related to the Excel version you use; I tested it with v.15 (actual v). What do you use? I could try it with different Excel versions on some other Macs.

Comment: I'm using 14.6.4 excel version.

Comment: Now I tried to solve it for the Excel 14.6.4 version; there are some differences in the protection techniques this version uses compared to the 15.xx one. You can protect the opening process itself; I added a script for this below

Comment: set theResult to ""
set passwd to "1234" -- whatever you want
set theWb to "/Volumes/yyy/workbook1.xls" -- example file
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
 set theResult to open workbook workbook file name theWb ¬
  password passwd
end tell